# What is the fastest way to release a new package version on pub.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pub.dev

I have published a package to pub.dev and I am making small changes. What is the easiest way to change all the package numbers in all the files? I usually search for the current version number in all files, for example 1.0.3 and replace it with 1.0.4, but this looks tedious. I am wondering if there is a better way? Like a function that updates the version with 1+.

Comment: In all which files?  The only files you need to change are `pubspec.yaml`, possibly `README.md`, and `CHANGELOG.md` (in which you should be *adding*, not replacing).  If you're putting package version numbers in all of your source files, then maybe you should stop doing that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. There is a version 1.0.3 in: a lot actually in ios/..., including podfile.lock, .podspec.json, Pods-Runner-Info.plist and more, also in /example/linux/.../readme, macos/podfile.lock other in macos, and other in /example/...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vscode, you could make a replace all operation over all files :

1. first, click the search icon on the left bar

[image: vscode]

2. fill in the text you want to search and the text which you want to change with

[image: vscode]

3. Click the replace all button

[image: vscode]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I am doing it this way, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it so that I don't have to manually replace it. Like a CLI that enables me to 1+ the version.